# Is there a way to reload a full on command folder in djs?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I am still learning JS, and I have asked around just a little bit but I haven't gotten any responses yet, but I am wondering if there is a way to create a module reload command so I don't have to constantly re-node my bot. Below is my current reload command that I work off of to at least reload a changed command, but I want to reload an entire module so I can work out added commands.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const eembeds = require(`../../embeds/embeds`);
const config = require(`../../config`);
const Command = require(`../../base/Command`);

class Reload extends Command {
    constructor (client) {
        super (client, {
            name: `reload`,
            dirname: __dirname,
            enabled: true,
            guildOnly: true,
            aliases: [`rl`],
            memberPermissions: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
            botPermissions: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'EMBED_LINKS'],
            nsfw: false,
            cooldown: 15,
            ownerOnly: false,
        });
    }

    async run (client, message, args){
        await message.delete().catch(() => {});
        const command = args[0];
        const cmd = this.client.commands.get(command) || this.client.commands.get(this.client.aliases.get(command));

        if(message.author.id === config.administrators.owner || message.author.id === config.administrators.admin || message.author.id === config.administrators.admin2 || message.author.id === config.administrators.dev || message.author.id === config.administrators.dev2){
            if(!cmd) {
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                .setTitle(`:warning: Error In: Command :warning:`)
                .setColor(0xFFD700)
                .setDescription(`Hey <@${message.author.id}>! That command could not be found!`)
                .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
                .setFooter(config.copyright);
                await message.channel.send(`Hey <@${message.author.id}>!`, embed);
            }
            else {
                //
                await this.client.unloadCommand(cmd.conf.location, cmd.help.name);
                await this.client.loadCommand(cmd.conf.location, cmd.help.name);
                client.logger.log(`Loading Command: ${cmd.help.name}.`, "log");
                //

                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                .setTitle(`Done!`)
                .setColor(0xA1EE33)
                .setDescription(`Hey <@${message.author.id}>! I have reloaded \`${cmd.help.name}\`!`)
                .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
                .setFooter(config.copyright);
                await message.channel.send(`Hey <@${message.author.id}>!`, embed);
            }
        }
        else { 
            await message.channel.send(`Hey <@${message.author.id}>!`, eembeds.UserPermsA);
        };
    };
};

module.exports = Reload;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure this out, I just had to use my command loader to make it work.